# How to combine columns within a table (Access SQL)

Tags: sql, ms-access

There are three columns of date information (month, day, year) in a table and I would like to create a new column in the table and combine those 3 columns into a the new column so that I can have a single formatted date. How can I do this? I know how to query this but I am trying to figure out how to copy this information to the original table. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look at the `DATESERIAL` function.

Comment: please add the working query you have.

Comment: What data type are your 3 existing columns?

Answer (score 2):

If I understood well, you need to alter your table and add a datetime column 
You need to do something like this

```
UPDATE YourTable
SET DATECOLUMN = '#' & DAYCOLUMN & '/' & MONTHCOLUMN & '/' & YEARCOLUMN & '#'
```

It was the sintaxis in access if i remember it well.

Greetings.

Comment: I tried the following and I got the error "Microsift access didn't update 10 fields due to a type conversion failure":


`update Autographs
set full_date = '#' & day & '/' & month & '/' & year& '#';`

Comment: The type conversion errors are probably from some invalid day, month or year values in your fields that are causing an invalid date to be generated. Look for values like Day=30 and Month=2.

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of way of managing such a data scrubbing exercise e.g.

- `CREATE` a new table including a new `NOT NULL` column and omitting the now-redundant columns, `INSERT..SELECT` into the new table only the data you require, DROP the old table (you'll end up with a different table name which may not be a bad thing).
- `ADD` a new nullable column to the existing table (or `NOT NULL` if you have an appropriate `DEFAULT`), `UPDATE` the new column, alter the column to make it `NOT NULL` then `DROP` the now-redundant columns.